# Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am getting following error after I convert in API 24.0.0

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not connect to GoogleApiClient: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incorrect provider authority in manifest. Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle     
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incorrect provider authority in manifest. Most likely due to a missing applicationId variable in application's build.gradle.
```

Answer (score 0):

so try sticking applicationId to your modules gradle, at defaultConfig like

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```